# How can I implement myself a MATLAB 'filter' function as direct form I?

Tags: matlab, filter

The Matlab `filter` function was written as direct-form II transposed. But I need for `the direct-form I` filter.

Comment: Does it really matter? Any of the two forms should give the same results, it's just an implementation thing